# Refresh WebPage periodically

Tags: html, page-refresh

My requirement is that i have a .php page that has to display some graphs/data based on data from a database. I would like refresh the page automatically and periodically so that graphs/data can be updated, as the data is obtained only on loading of the page. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can try the setTimeout javascript method

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
```

this would refresh the page on every timeoutPeriod interval.

Comment: No problem. But I think refreshing the whole page for intervals might be annoying for the viewers. If the interval between each refresh is small I suggest using ajax instead.

Comment: Okay. Actually i've just started reading on AJAX so i think i should go for it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use javascript.

JS function

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
```

Add below line on body tag.

```
 <body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);"> // time : 5000= 5 secs
```