# Change Which Table Row Background Color Changes Thoughout the Day Based on Time 0f Day

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML file that statically displays my school's schedule. How can I get table rows to change background color throughout the day based on time? I want the homeroom row to have a different background color only during homeroom and then return to normal when the row for first period has the different background color. And so on throughout the day.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Schedule 1</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}
table, th, td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
th {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
}
td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 80px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 160px;
}
.table {
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<br><br>
<h1 style="color:white; bgcolor:black">SCHEDULE 1</h1>
<div class="table">
<table class="schedule">
 <tr>  <th width="300" colspan="2">REGULAR</th> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>HR</td><td>8:04 - 8:17</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>1</td><td>8:21 - 9:06</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>2</td><td>9:10 - 9:55</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>3</td><td>9:59 - 10:44</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>4</td><td>10:48 - 11:33</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>5</td><td>11:37 - 12:22</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>6</td><td>12:26 - 1:11</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>7</td><td>1:15 - 2:01</td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td>8</td><td>2:05 - 2:50</td> </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you written any JavaScript to try and accomplish this?

Comment: No. I've only just started looking at the w3schools site because I suspected that javascript might be a likely solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar to this, this uses jQuery. In your javascript, find out whether it is day or night (you could check for more times if you want) then depending on the result, update your dom styles. (This is in 24 hour format, you can change it to 12 hour format to make your `if/else` statements easier like this: `((hourCompare + 11) % 12 + 1)`

```
var d = new Date();
var hourCompare = d.getHours();
if (hourCompare >= 8 && hourCompare <= 22) {
    //day time
    $('.tableCell').css("background-color", "yellow");
} else {
    //night time
    $('.tableCell').css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

I put together a jsfiddle for you. In order to get the correct colors, you will essentially have to write an `if` statement for each hour that you want to find and update the colors like I did in the fiddle. I wrote it to check for time updates every 3 seconds with `setInterval`. https://jsfiddle.net/zu588wjr/1/

Comment: Thank you for the script.  I'll give 'er a whirl.  Will this execute only upon opening the page or will it keep checking the time all day long?  I need it to do the latter, not the former.  BTW, I have zero experience with javascript.  I am, however, looking at the w3schools.com site to start learning.

Comment: This will only execute on page load, but you can wrap it inside a function that will call it every x minutes. Are you wanting to accomplish this with the html you posted above? I can throw together a jsfiddle for you if needed.

Comment: I edited my answer and provided a jsFiddle, let me know if that works. If so, please mark my answer correct.

Comment: I've never seen a jsFiddle before. How cool.  Thanks Austin! In between job duties, I've been studying and modifying the jsFiddle to see what I can learn, what I'm understanding, and where I'm going astray. Unfortunately, when I try what I'm learning on my laptop, I'm not having success... yet. When I understand things a little better, I'll report what I'm seeing.

Comment: The changes I've made to the jsFiddle in the javascript window appear to be working. However, my HTML file does not seem to recognize my .js file. I've put the following just above the </body> closing tag.

<script src="js_script.js"></script>

Is this the proper place or have I misunderstood what I read at w3schools?

Comment: @Foxy It could not be working because you need to link the jQuery library. Make sure this is in your HTML document `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` if that does not work please view your browser console and let me know what it says. (You can do that by right-clicking > inspect > click console)

Comment: That's exactly what I just did about 30 minutes ago! After googling for why javascript wan't working, I finally ran into something mentioning the jQuery library. I downloaded 3.2.0 and things started working.  Since then, I've been writing code and it is all working.  Many thanks. The only part of your answer that isn't working is the setinterval function. But I found a solution two days ago elsewhere on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944297/refresh-webpage-periodically

Comment: My next goal is to get resolution better than one hour. My if-else statements will need to also compare minutes. I will look through w3schools to see if nested () are allowed. Many thanks for your help. Your jsFiddle did the trick.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. Yes you should be able to swap out the date functions. Find one on w3schools that tracks minutes and you can append that to the current one and check that way.